# The 2D and 3D graphics engines that Chrome and Servo use

Tags: c++, c, browser, graphics

I learned a while back (after many hours searching) that Chrome/Webkit uses [Cairo graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_(graphics)) for it's (at least) *2D* drawing. I am not sure what it does for 3D. But if you search for "graphics engine used by chrome" you get a bunch of stuff about [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)), but this is not what you want....

Looking briefly at the [Servo](https://github.com/servo/servo) browser, you see [servo/servo/blob/master/components/canvas/webgl_mode/inprocess.rs#L13](https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/de3d2f74951bf0c0834dfda8837d934b3e88aff2/components/canvas/webgl_mode/inprocess.rs#L13) which links to [servo/gleam](https://github.com/servo/gleam) which from what it [seems](https://github.com/servo/gleam/blob/f3cd94719abb7e7c7d27e0d5e18f63c8b9371c2e/src/gl.rs#L93-L551) is the abstraction layer providing OpenGL support in Servo. But I haven't yet seen where it actually connects to the operating-system specific "drivers" or what have you for graphics, like [Cairo](https://github.com/freedesktop/cairo) does (I would think). Come to think of it, I am not sure how Cairo [abstracts](https://github.com/freedesktop/cairo/blob/9752636bade11a9b3a3f65367c2b3728ca60a983/src/win32/cairo-win32-display-surface.c) windows/darwin/linux, that would be interesting to know.

So my questions are:

1. The graphics engine(s) (2D and 3D) that Chrome and Servo are using.
2. Where they do the actual operating-system-level connection to the graphics drivers or system-level APIs for the OS.

I would like to see how a large-scale graphics engine connects to the native graphics. Like nowadays they might just connect to Metal API for iOS, for example, rather than something higher-level. I am not sure what they connect to on Mac and Windows and Linux. I am interested to see the source code for it.

I have heard of [Mesa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)) but not sure if these projects are using it for 3D or not.

Comment: Some interesting information from a book: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EZuJAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=blink+webgraphicscontext3d&source=bl&ots=cnlURFS7OZ&sig=ACfU3U1Ealk29mxZs-RFMBXNo5FnLhx53Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ2vKJtOHgAhWQkxQKHSyxDPw4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=blink%20webgraphicscontext3d&f=false